# SELECT statement duplicating score for every record?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I'm trying to write a SELECT statement that will display Bowlers who have a raw score of over 190, in a game that they're team lost.

This code retrieves 960 results, and everyone has either a score of 192 or 193, everyone is displayed on every team, and every team plays multiple times in the same game.

```
SELECT bs.MATCHID "Match", t.TEAMNAME "Team Name", 
   b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || b.BOWLERLASTNAME "Bowler Name", 
   bs.GAMENUMBER "Game Number", bs.RAWSCORE "Raw Score"
FROM BOWLER_SCORES bs, TEAMS t, BOWLERS b, MATCH_GAMES m
WHERE bs.MATCHID = m.MATCHID
AND bs.GAMENUMBER = m.GAMENUMBER
AND bs.WONGAME = 'N'
AND bs.RAWSCORE >= 190;
```

You can see how this is obviously wrong, and I'm doing something wrong, fundamentally, in the code. I'm just not sure what it is, and what I should do differently.

I'm very new to SQL, so any additional advice or pointers you have are much appreciated.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: It would appear you seem to be missing how some of the tables relate. For example you show how bowler_scores relate to match_games, but not how teams or bowlers relate to either of these tables.  As such you have a cross join in data where all bowlers and teams are going to multiply the records in match_games and bowler scores #of Teams * number of Bowlers * # of records where bowler_Scores.matchID = match_Games.MatchID. and BS.GameNumber = M.gameNumber.  So if you had 10 bowlers, 5 matches and 150 bowler scores you'd end up with 7500 records when you likely only wanted 150.

Comment: @Parfait: none of the reasons why Oracle developers used to argue with are valid any more though

Comment: @Parfait -- are you really arguing that a bug in the product from 18 years ago has a bearing on what people should be doing now?

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you kindly to xQbert and Gordon Linoff!

I've got it displaying correctly now!

Here's the updated code snippet:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MATCHID "Match", TEAMNAME "Team Name", 
   BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || BOWLERLASTNAME "Bowler Name", 
   bs.GAMENUMBER "Game Number", bs.RAWSCORE "Raw Score"
FROM BOWLERS
   JOIN TEAMS USING (TEAMID)
   JOIN BOWLER_SCORES bs USING (BOWLERID)
   JOIN MATCH_GAMES m USING (MATCHID)
WHERE bs.WONGAME = 'N'
  AND bs.RAWSCORE >= 190
ORDER BY "Match" ASC;
```

Comment: Your specific issue of original query is that you had a `CROSS JOIN` on *Teams* and *Bowlers* tables as they had no condition in `WHERE`. Hence, why one should use explicit joins as with implicit, one can easily create cartesian products!